# on the job market / in the job market

Tags: prepositions

> Student debt keeps rising for a degree that may be worthless **on** the job market.
>
> Student debt keeps rising for a degree that may be worthless **in** the job market.

Is there a difference? As far as I know 'on the market' is for sale and 'in the market' is more about specific locations, but what should we use when we talk in general about the job market?

Comment: `In the job market` is colloquial US English. Perhaps you're thinking of "on the job," i.e., at work.

Comment: At work? No, I mean the whole "environment" of jobs, like you graduate and then start looking for a job. You could for example ask "What are the best companies for young college grads now entering the job market?"

Comment: The "in" is the preposition to use.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Not necessarily. I believe the OP is trying to draw a parallel between merchandise "on the market" and a person/form of labor "on the job market". You would say _The house has been on (not in) the market for years._ In fact "on the job market" is [not totally unheard of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+job+market%2Cin+the+job+market&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: Could be, I've just never heard it used that way in this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more idiomatic preposition that goes with *the job market* is usually "in".

> The demand for skilled electricians in the job market can vary from country to country.

But I definitely see where you are coming from. I gather you are drawing a parallel between  merchandise "on the market" and a person or a form of labor "on the job market".

It is true that we often talk about a product/commodity being "**on** the market", while the trader of the commodity is "**in** the market".

> How long has this house been on the market?

But as with any other language, English has exceptions to almost every rule and idiomatic usage. Prepositions are tricky. You can also talk about commodities being in the market. This usage is less common but not uncommon:

> "It's one of the biggest scandals in my memory," Richard Feigen, an Old Master art dealer in New York, told Bloomberg after last year's revelations about **forgeries in the market**. ([NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/01/18/510414194/sothebys-contends-painting-that-sold-for-842-500-is-a-fake))

It'd make sense your intuition tells you "on the job market" might work. And it does, though not so popular as "in the job market", as this Google Ngram chart shows:

[image]

Examples:

> Anyone hearing that would assume he was working on a startup, and certainly not **on the job market**. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=rXT2rMRtOiMC&pg=PA107&dq=%22on%20the%20job%20market%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB2ejkx4jjAhVlk-AKHcuoApsQ6AEIXzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22on%20the%20job%20market%22&f=false))
>
> In the US market at least, I think it's better for students to show a portfolio of skills **on the job market**. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=YFH3Tn9RPxAC&pg=PA9&dq=%22skills%20on%20the%20job%20market%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAzaiR0IjjAhWLmOAKHfRuCoEQ6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%22skills%20on%20the%20job%20market%22&f=false), from [Catherine Eckel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_C._Eckel))
>
> with the over-supply of **university degrees on the job market**, employers have increasingly sought post-secondary graduates to fill job vacancies in middle-skills jobs that were previously performed by employees with a high school diploma ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=qfd1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&dq=%22degrees%20on%20the%20job%20market%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnmJ6V0YjjAhXqct8KHccOCLgQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22degrees%20on%20the%20job%20market%22&f=false))

To sum, your sentence could go either way, although "in the job market" is certainly more common than "on the job market".